# Synchronisation mechanisms (e.g. locks) in Firefox extensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, synchronization, firefox-addon

Can I have some synchronisation mechanism (e.g. locks) in a Firefox extension's JavaScript code?

I added code according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/On_page_load to make my extension do something each time a page is loaded, and I want to control the sequence of functions that are run inside my extension's JavaScript code.

Is there some way to achieve this using some synchronisation mechanism (e.g. locks) in a Firefox extension's JavaScript code?

Just as a wild guess, do I need to use web workers for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'm doing it right now is to use [Dekker's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker's_algorithm) where the shared variables are put inside a [JavaScript code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using).

Right now I only need to synchronize 2 things, for synchronizing more things [some solutions for software mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion#Software_solutions) can be used.

This kind of busy wait can make Firefox get stuck (maybe due to how Firefox handles processes and threads?), so I do not advise using anything like this.

A better solution would be to use events, as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Adding_Events_and_Commands#Custom_events) on Mozilla's website.

Maybe there are other options. There are some interesting answers at [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) for your flow-control